# Is "they do also" acceptable US English grammar?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wrote the following sentence recently:

> These ongoing costs bring benefits of auditability, security, and convenience for users, but they do also increase complexity and running costs.

Google Docs wants me to remove the "do" from "they do also." I'm a native English speaker (US) and I think Google's suggestion, while not precisely wrong, eliminates meaning and useful cadence from my sentence.

My questions:

1. Is my use of "they do also" in this context acceptable for standard English (non-jargon-y business) grammar?
2. Is my use of this phrase overly elaborate, and/or my meaning better served by eliminating the "do"?

Comment: Tell Google Docs to go take a flying F. Both ways of doing this are grammatical, but use of *do* is a standard way to bring emphasis to that type of clause.

Comment: See [writing.se]

Comment: I feel like it would more grammatically correct to say 'also do increase', since in 'do increase' you're using 'do' to emphasize the main verb. But, hey, I don't think Google Docs is paying attention to that, and I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, there is no rule regarding the use of adverbs in that type of construction.

Comment: @Alberto: Whether you put *do* before or after *also* is a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: @Robusto - thanks. To be fair to Google's grammarbot, it does say "consider using 'they also'" -- so it wasn't saying necessarily my usage was incorrect, but I didn't view the suggestion as a change a reasonable ELA teacher would ask for (kind of my minimum rubric for what grammar changes must be made).